# JavaScript - How to tell if the user has just returned to the previous page

Tags: javascript, php, browser-history

I have a two page process for the user. When the user submits the first page via ajax, it saves the values to the session. If the user goes back in their browser, the first page UI is reloaded to its previous state with JavaScript using the session values.

However, the first page can also be pre-filled via query string parameters. If the query string parameters are present, any existing session needs to be ignored, otherwise the user will never be able to follow new links to the first page pre-filled with a new set of values (it will always just override the values with the same ones from their last session).

The session only gets cleared if they complete Page 2.

I have one problem with this. If the user goes to the second page and then goes back via their browser history, back button, etc., we can assume they do in fact want to see the previous page with their current session values in it, and not reset that first page to whatever was in the query string when they originally came to page 1.

To clarify the logic here:

```
Page 1

Does user have existing session?
     |
    No ---- Is query string present?
     |           |
     |          No  ---- Load default view
     |           |
     |          Yes ---- Load from query string
     |
     |
    Yes --- Is query string present?
                 |
                No  ---- Load from session
                 |
                Yes ---- Did user just come directly back from Page 2?
                             |
                            No  ---- Load from query string
                             |
                            Yes ---- Load from session
```

It is the very last piece here which I'm not sure how to do in a tidy way. I know I could solve this by logging every page request on the site and checking if the previous one was Page 2, but I'd like to know if there is a simpler way with less overhead, just using JavaScript.

Comment: You could use the History API to replace the current location entry, when the user arrives on page 1 - with the query-string-less URL of page 1.

Comment: @misorude Good idea. You should post as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the History API to replace the current location entry, when the user arrives on page 1 - with the query-string-less URL of page 1.

If they then go back from page 2, it should load page 1 without any GET parameters.

Comment: This is a fairly good solution, but has a problem. When the user is linked to the first page with a query string, the QS immediately gets removed from the URL so if they reload the page it doesn't reload the UI as per the original query string parameters, which is slightly annoying or confusing for the user.

Comment: For the server, there is little difference between a request that reloads a page, or one that goes back to the page via history. Even if you tried to use the referrer to somehow make that distinction (despite how unreliably it is to begin with), if the user came back from page 2 to page 1, and then page 1 gets reloaded, it would probably still show the referrer as being page 2 … I don’t think you can really have it both ways.

Comment: Maybe a different approach altogether … Like, leave the query string as it is, and pre-populate the fields with those values, no matter which “direction” I am navigating in. If I _have_ values in the session, you could show me an alert or a button, asking me whether I want to take the values from my session instead. If so, make an AJAX request in the background, that fetches those values and puts them into the form fields …